# Can a smooth manifold be realised as the image of a smooth function?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

Consider, $M$, a smooth $m$ dimensional submanifold of $\mathbf R^n$. Does there exist a smooth map $X: \mathbf{R}^m\to\mathbf R^n$ such that $M$ is the image of $X$?

Comment: What have you tried? Any special cases or trivial obstructions, for instance? Why does this question interest you?

Comment: @Aphelli This question originates from string theory where one represents the 2d worldsheet in $\mathbf R^n$ by coordinate functions $X^\mu(t,\sigma)$. My own feeling was that any smooth map $X: \mathbf R^m\to \mathbf R^n$ will be a diffeomorphism, so that only manifolds diffeomorphic to $\mathbf R^m$ can be realised as the image of $X$; however, I realised that the stereographic projection is a smooth map between manifolds of different topology. Hence the question...

Comment: @Aphelli ...Also, if the smooth map has non-invertible Jacobian somewhere, then it is not a diffeomorphism, which opens up the possibility that any manifold can be realised as the image of such a map. Hence the question.

Comment: Indeed, you can’t restrict to diffeomorphisms. I suggest that you try $M=S^1$, then $M=S^2$.

Comment: Certainly, it is not true that the only smooth maps are diffeomorphisms. For example, the torus is definitely a smooth image of $\mathbb R^2.$

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/431338/can-a-smooth-manifold-be-realised-as-the-image-of-a-smooth-function